# Azure AD Admin Consent via PowerShell?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Today it appears the only way to grant OAuth consent as an admin for an Azure Active Directory application is via the Azure portal.  Is there any way to do this programmatically via PowerShell?  If not, are there any plans to add this support in the future?

Comment: Steve, I've written a PowerShell function to set permissions on Azure AD application in general (delegated permissions and application permissions). 

See https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims/blob/master/Configure.ps1#L105-L124 


I'm not sure though that this will also provide admin consent.

Comment: Awesome, that is very helpful.  Thank you for sharing that.

Comment: You will need to create OAuth2PermissionGrants for delegated permissions (with consentType="AllPrincipals" and principalId=null) and AppRoleAssignments for app permissions (on the app's service principal). I believe you can do the second one with `New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment`, not sure if there is a cmdlet for the first. Anyway, this is what the button does.

Comment: @juunas which library does that commandlet you reference come from?  I don't see that one in the Azure SDK for PowerShell.

Comment: Azure AD powershell v2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0

Comment: This has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346121/powershell-do-grant-permissions-action-on-azure-ad-application-with-powershe/49750632#49750632

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to grant the **admin consent** for the Azure ad app.

It is easy to give the admin consent for the app, we just need to add the additional parameter `prompt` parameter with the value `admin_consent`. For example below is a request go give the admin consent:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F
&state=12345
&prompt=admin_consent
```

You can just visit this URL to give the admin consent for the app(`6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e`). And if you want to implement it through PowerShell, we just need to navigate this URL through PowerShell. For example, we can use `Start-Process` command-let like below:

```
Start-Process -FilePath  "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&response_mode=query&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F&state=12345&prompt=admin_consent"
```

More detail about the parameters in the OAuth protocol, you can refer the link below:

[Authorize access to web applications using OAuth 2.0 and Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code)

And it is different to grant the admin consent for the Azure AD V2.0 endpoint, you can refer the link below about grant the admin consent for the Azure AD V2.0 endpoint.

[Using the admin consent endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
az ad app permission admin-consent --id $appId
```